# Оптимальное хранение редких длинных строк в БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Какой объем памяти резервируют под себя ПУСТЫЕ поля типа `longtext` на жестком диске сервера?

Короче говоря,  поле изначально имело тип `text`. Увы, несколько записей будут иметь значительно больший объем, чем 64 КБ. Значит, мне придется изменить тип на `medium` или `longtext`. Как это скажется на величине базы данных, если большинство таких полей будут практически пустыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MEDIUMTEXT` не хранит всю строку, а хранит толко указатель. Строка храниться отдельно и занимает (<длина строки> + 3) байт.

**Обновление**

`TEXT` имеет длину  `<длина строки> + 2` (2 байта для хранения длины, т.е. макс длина 2^16).

`MEDIUMTEXT` имеет длину  `<длина строки> + 3` (3 байта для хранения длины, т.е. макс длина 2^24).

В этом, я так понимаю, вся разница.

Comment: @Deus, Обновил ответ